# Qt::BackgroundRole seems to be ignored

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm using a custom table model derived from `QAbstractTableModel`.

I've overwritter `headerData()` and I can change the font color for individual row-headers (or column-header, but I'm all about rows here) by returning the color on `Qt::ForegroundRole`

```
if(role == Qt::ForegroundRole)
   return Qt::green;
```

But if I go for `Qt::BackgroundRole` to set the background color of the header cells, nothing happens.

```
if(role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
   return Qt::red;
```

I set a breakpoint on the `return` and it is reached. But nothing happens :-(

Any ideas on where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK the role colours are equivalent to setting a palette colour, the `QStyle` drawing the header cells is free to ignore it.

I've had trouble using `QPalette` or style sheets to set arbitrary colours on widgets.  Text tends to work, as do 'window' coloured backgrounds (a `QPushButton` background for example), but text entry field backgrounds don't (`QLineEdit` for example).  But AFAIK it's down to the particular `QStyle` implementation, so will vary not only across widgets, but also across platforms.  The only *certain* way to get things exactly how you want is to reimplement `QStyle` (a *big* job), or paint it manually in `paintEvent(..)` (difficult to follow the current `QStyle` and still lots of code).

Comment: So the background color cant be set like this? :-(

Answer (score 1):

1) You can also achieve it by using own item delegates - inherit from QStyledItemDelegate or whatever else, reimplement one method and set it to view.

2) For specific table or header view, use style that respects brushes:

```
//auto keys = QStyleFactory::keys();
if(auto style = QStyleFactory::create("Fusion")) {
    verticalHeader()->setStyle(style);
}
```